# Java Catch Object Error

Tags: java, try-catch

This code below is the method header and body, but I get the following error:  `no exception of type object can be thrown an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable`.  I'm attempting to execute this block of code:  `catch(Object object)`.

```
public void method15665(Class435 class435, int i) {
    do {
        try {
            try {
                byte[] is
                        = new byte[(int) class435.method7563(1085678935)];
                int i_3_;
                for (int i_4_ = 0; i_4_ < is.length; i_4_ += i_3_) {
                    i_3_ = class435.method7564(is, i_4_, is.length - i_4_,
                            (byte) -10);
                    if (i_3_ == -1)
                        throw new EOFException();
                }
                Class224_Sub8 class224_sub8 = new Class224_Sub8(is);
                if ((class224_sub8.aByteArray8535.length
                        - class224_sub8.anInt8536 * 475822179)
                        < 1) {
                    try {
                        class435.method7572(-1683167102);
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
            /* empty */
                    }
                    break;
                }
                int i_5_ = class224_sub8.method13859((short) -7287);
                if (i_5_ < 0 || i_5_ > 1) {
                    try {
                        class435.method7572(-1683167102);
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
            /* empty */
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if ((class224_sub8.aByteArray8535.length
                        - class224_sub8.anInt8536 * 475822179)
                        < 2) {
                    try {
                        class435.method7572(-1683167102);
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
            /* empty */
                    }
                    break;
                }
                int i_6_ = class224_sub8.method13737(2071056893);
                if ((class224_sub8.aByteArray8535.length
                        - 475822179 * class224_sub8.anInt8536)
                        < 6 * i_6_) {
                    try {
                        class435.method7572(-1683167102);
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
            /* empty */
                    }
                    break;
                }
                for (int i_7_ = 0; i_7_ < i_6_; i_7_++) {
                    Class323 class323
                            = Class399.aClass195_Sub2_Sub1_5932
                            .method14614(class224_sub8, -2141543778);
                    if ((Class255.aClass255_3016
                            == (((Class173_Sub1) this).aClass255Array9960
                            [class323.anInt5015 * 1568411443]))
                            && (Class399.aClass195_Sub2_Sub1_5932.method14624
                            (class323.anInt5015 * 1568411443, 82620551)
                            .aClass350_2171.method6687
                                    (-1035085164).aClass5162.isAssignableFrom
                                    (class323.anObject5014.getClass())))
                        anInterface50_2149.method298((class323.anInt5015
                                * 1568411443),
                                class323.anObject5014,
                                -1250481088);
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                try {
                    class435.method7572(-1683167102);
                } catch (Exception exception_8_) {
                    exception = exception_8_;
                }
                break;
            }
            try {
                class435.method7572(-1683167102);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
        /* empty */
            }
        } catch (Object object) {
            try {
                class435.method7572(-1683167102);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
        /* empty */
            }
            throw object;
        }
    } while (false);
}
```

Does anyone know how fix this? It would be very much appreciated!

Comment: wow, some catchy methods and classes names

Comment: is it decompiled java class file which obfuscated before?

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
} catch (Object object) {
```

with

```
} catch (Throwable object) {
```

actually you don't want to catch `Throwable`, but probably `Exception`, `RuntimeException` or an even more specific class.

Comment: Why not `Throwable`? Perfectly legit if you want to call that method in case of any error (which is a very typical requirement).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik catching Throwable is typically a bad idea, because Errors aren't intended to been catched. When an Error is thrown, you can't be sure of anything. Maybe classes are missing, or you are out of memory. Of course there are exceptions to the rule.

Comment: Rather, it is the usual case. If you disagree, just check out any public libraries, such as Spring, Swing, or SWT, which contain main loops or main request-processing contexts. The all, invariably, catch `Throwable`, perform some cleanup, and swallow the exception.

Comment: The point "you can't be sure of anything" is quite irrelevant. If your decision is crash the server or swallow the excption and see what happens, what do you think should be preferred? Have you ever seen a Web server which collapses due to a trivial `StackOverflowError` or `OutOfMemoryError` caused by some silly infinite loop somewhere in the service layer?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik so because some libraries do catch Throwable it is in general a good idea? That is a somewhat convoluted logic.

Comment: No, it is a good argument. Do you maintain that the developers of Eclipse Core, Java Development Kit, and Spring Framework are all, collectively, following bad practices?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I never said that. And arguing there are (possibly valid) usages of practice X therefor X is a good practice in general is a bad argument.

Comment: No, it just means that what stands for X is not "catch `Throwable` wherever" (a wickerman you seem to be slipping in), but "catch `Throwable` at the top control level, where there are no further exception handlers above you" and "never, ever  swallow a `Throwable` at the service layer or below." Catching it is still alright, BTW, if you make sure you rethrow.

Comment: In other words, you said "catching Throwable is typically a bad idea" but the truth is "catching Throwable judiciously is a very good idea" and even "failing to catch Throwable at the appropriate place is a very bad idea."

Answer (score 2):

You can only *catch* what can be *thrown* (IS-A `Throwable`). Hence, the compiler complains when you try to catch an *Object* (because it doesn't extend *Throwable*).

```
catch (Object o) // Error: Object IS-NOT Throwable
```

`Throwable` is inherited by all types of `Error`s and `Exception`s. But, we usually don't catch `Error`s because a program almost always cannot recover from it for example, an *OutOfMemoryError*. So, a `catch (Throwable t)` **is not** recommended.

When using `catch (Exception e)` you basically have a ***catch-all*** for any exception (*checked* or *un-checked*) that might get thrown during the run. To use or not to use a generic catch usually depends on what you're `try` block is trying to do. For example, when reading a file you would like to handle and respond to a `FileNotFoundException` differently than say an `EOFException`.

Answer (score 0):

All exceptions and errors extend `Throwable`, only those can be thrown and caught.

You can do

```
 try{
    throw new Exception();
  }catch(Exception e){
    // something here
  }catch(Throwable t){
    // something here
  }
```

When you are writing multiple catch blocks, then keep following points in mind

- You cannot write a subclass type AFTER a superclass type. i.e. If you write `catch(RuntimeException rt){}` AFTER `catch(Exception e){}` then you will get compiler error that it is already caught.